# Create File on Target Server Using Ansible

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to create a file on the target server using Ansible.

I would like to get the path from the env variable on the target server.

The code is:

```
- name: Create a file 
  win_file: 
    path: ansible_env.CONFIG_HOME\conf\xyz.txt
    state: file
```

The error I'm receiving is:

> "changed": false,
>
> "msg": "path ansible_env.CONFIG_HOME\conf\xyz.txt will not be created"

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues here.

Firstly, since you are trying to use an environment *variable*, you need braces `{{ }}` to interpolate the value.

Secondly, have a close read of the [docs](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/windows/win_file_module.html#parameter-state) for `win_file` where it talks about the way `state` behaves:

> If `file`, the file will NOT be created if it does not exist
>
> If `touch`, an empty file will be created if the path does not exist

Taking into consideration the above, the following should work for you:

```
- name: Create a file 
  win_file: 
    path: "{{ ansible_env.CONFIG_HOME }}\conf\xyz.txt"
    state: touch
```